# Can multiple files be selected, then uploaded to U1 simultaneously?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Have I just not figured out yet how to mark and upload [multiple] files, or must they be uploaded only one at a time? I would like to have a Ubuntu One folder on my machines and put files in it, then upload them all in one swell foop. Is this not possible? If the answer is 'No' is it at least in the works?

Answer (score 1):

If you have UbuntuOne set up just drop the files in the folder and they will upload and sync across your other computers with UbuntuOne

Comment: Correct. Adding files to an Ubuntu One synced folder on your computer will make them all upload at once, rather than one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring from the website, no, you currently can't upload multiple files at once.
It is on our roadmap, so you will see this feature sometime between now and the end of the year  :)